# Application breaking, warning Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'some' of undefined in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have 3 sections of the application, one is form for filling about watches, data is being submitted by submitHandler function. 
Second part is entered watches from the first part of the application. When I click on buy of the each watch, should be added to the third part of the application, with the restriction that the same watches(with the same name) should be only added once - should be unique, and i should spot it by application, and not to enable adding to third part of the same watches.

Below is my code with 2 functions, parent function buyWatchHandler that is invoking add function. 
buyWatchHandler function is receiving input parameters(watch details) from form fields collected by submitHandler and that works perfectly. In buyWatchHandler i have let arr that is invoking add functions, and in arr variable should be set the resulting array from add function.
When we enter in add function, the input parameters are well forwarded. There in I am setting arr to value of state variable this.state.selectedWatchList. 
Here emerges the problem. I am using "some" method for arrays to check if the value of name of the watch received as selectedWatchName(input) is the same as the one in object of arr as el.selectedWatchName. If yes it is returned true, and I want not forward to invoking function. The logical result(true or false) is set into found. If found is false, or to be clear - value of element is not the same as the one from arr(unique watch), I want to concatenate to variable arr the value of the selectedWatchName and the values of the other input parameters of add function. 
In invoking function we should receive in let arr the forwarded array, and should be added to state variable selectedWatchList.

When I click on buy button first time in console is being printed false for found method which is logical, as the el.selectedWatchName is empty and different from selectedWatchName(input), arr from add function is being empty printed and should be not empty as well as this.state.selectedWatchList in buyWatchHandler is being printed empty. On second click selectedWatchList is filled with data, found is true which is ok, as i am trying to add the same watch to array of selectedWatchList. On third click the application is breaking, and I do not know the reason, Can anyone spot what is wrong, and why is breaking? The warning is the following: App.js:66 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'some' of undefined. The buy button should be functioning also on third click and every next, and should add each new unique name of the watch to selectedWatchList.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import EnteredWatches from '.././components/EnteredWatches/EnteredWatches';

    class App extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)

            this.state = {
                watchName: '',
                watchDescription: '',
                watchUrl: '',
                watchPrice: '',
                watchId: '',
                enteredWatchList: [],
                selectedWatchName: '',
                selectedWatchDescription: '',
                selectedWatchUrl: '',
                selectedWatchPrice: '',
                selectedWatchId: '',
                selectedWatchList: []
            }
        }

        submitHandler = (event) => {
                event.preventDefault();
                let watchId = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
                let watchName = this.state.watchName;
                let watchDescription = this.state.watchDescription;
                let watchUrl = this.state.watchUrl;
                let watchPrice = this.state.watchPrice;

                this.setState({
                    enteredWatchList: this.state.enteredWatchList.concat({watchName, watchUrl, watchDescription, watchPrice, watchId})
                })
                console.log(this.state.enteredWatchList);
            }

        add = (selectedWatchName, selectedWatchUrl, selectedWatchDescription, selectedWatchPrice, index) => {
            let arr = this.state.selectedWatchList;

            let found = arr.some(el => {
                return el.selectedWatchName === selectedWatchName;
            });
console.log(found);
            if (!found) { 
                return arr.concat({selectedWatchName, selectedWatchUrl, selectedWatchDescription, selectedWatchPrice, index});
            } 
console.log(arr);
        }

        buyWatchHandler = (selectedWatchName, selectedWatchUrl, selectedWatchDescription, selectedWatchPrice, index) => {

            let arr = this.add(selectedWatchName, selectedWatchUrl, selectedWatchDescription, selectedWatchPrice, index);

            this.setState({
                selectedWatchName: selectedWatchName,
                selectedWatchUrl: selectedWatchUrl,
                selectedWatchDescription: selectedWatchDescription,
                selectedWatchPrice: selectedWatchPrice,
                selectedWatchId: index,
                selectedWatchList: arr
            });
            console.log(this.state.selectedWatchList);
        }

        render() {
            const enteredWatches = this.state.enteredWatchList.map((enteredWatch, index) => {

                return <EnteredWatches
                    key={index}
                    enteredWatch={enteredWatch}
                    selected={this.buyWatchHandler.bind(this, enteredWatch.watchName, enteredWatch.watchUrl,
                        enteredWatch.watchDescription, enteredWatch.watchPrice, index)}
                />
            });

            return (
                <div className="App">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <div className="container">
                            <div className="add-product">
                               <form>
                                    <div>
                                        <label>Product name:</label>
                                        <input 
                                            type="text" 
                                            placeholder="Casio Watch" 
                                            value={this.state.watchName.}
                                            onChange={event => this.setState({watchName: event.target.value})}
                                        />
                                    </div>

                                    <div>
                                        <label>Product description:</label>
                                        <textarea 
                                            placeholder="Sample description..."
                                            value={this.state.watchDescription}
                                            onChange={event => this.setState({watchDescription: event.target.value})}
                                        >
                                        </textarea>
                                    </div>

                                    <div>
                                        <label>Product image:</label>
                                        <input 
                                            type="text" 
                                            placeholder="http://...jpg"
                                            value={this.state.watchUrl}
                                            pattern="https?://.+" required
                                            onChange={event => this.setState({watchUrl: event.target.value})}
                                        />
                                    </div>

                                    <div>
                                        <label>Product price:</label>
                                        <input 
                                            type="number" 
                                            min="0" 
                                            placeholder="33.50" 
                                            value={this.state.watchPrice}
                                            onChange={event => this.setState({watchPrice: event.target.value})}
                                        />
                                    </div>

                                    <button
                                        type="submit"
                                        onClick={event => this.submitHandler(event)}
                                    >
                                        Add a new Task
                                    </button>
                                </form>
                             </div>

                             <div className="list-products">    
                                <ul>
                                   {enteredWatches}
                                </ul> 
                            </div>

                            <div className="shopping-cart">
                                <div className="shopping-cart-products">

                                </div>
                                <div className="shopping-cart-summary">
                                    <div>Total: <b>$429</b></div>
                                    <div><button>Purchase</button></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default App;
```

Comment: What happens if you log `arr` in your `add` function, just before the `.some()`? I suspect there's a thing going on with your array concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your add method you only return `if(!found)`, yet the expectation in your code is that the `add()` method will always return an array.

Next, when `add` does not have an explicit `return` JavaScript returns `undefined` by default. Finally, you set the state of `selectedWatchList` to the value of `arr`..hence you get `.some()` trying to access an `undefined` value whenever a duplicate is entered.

To fix this, the `add` method should always return `this.selectedWatchList` given the condition of `if(found)` or as an `else` in your current code.